# FFMPEG gives improper "duration" in metadata

Tags: ffmpeg

Scenario: I have 5 minutes of gameplay footage. I wanted a 10 second clip in the middle of it as a webm to share.

```
ffmpeg -ss 3:36 -i gameplay.mp4 -copyts -to 3:46 -c:v libvpx -an -b:v 2500 -threads 7 -f webm clip.webm
```

This generates a clip that's 10 seconds long, but the timestamp starts at 3:36, not 0. To fix this, I ran:

```
ffmpeg -i clip.webm -c:v copy -f webm clip-tsfix.webm
```

This fixed the timestamps, but now my video still has a metadata tag claiming the total duration is 5 minutes, not 10 seconds. How do I fix this? Is there a way to do all of this in one go? I did try this, which seems to fix the timestamps but still has the duration metadata problem:

```
ffmpeg -ss 3:36 -i gameplay.mp4 -copyts -to 3:46 -c:v libvpx -an -b:v 2500 -filter_complex [v]scale=-1:720[vs] -map [vs] -threads 7 -f webm clip.webm
```

I think everything starts getting messed up once I use the -copyts flag, but without it, it doesn't process "-to" properly.

Comment: Share full log of `ffmpeg -i clip.webm -c:v copy -f webm clip-tsfix.webm`